# Total beginner wrote a tic tac toe game in Python and would like some feedback

Tags: python

I've decided to learn Python about 2 weeks ago, been going through various books and videos, and I've decided to try my hand at programming a tic tac toe game. I was somewhat successful (it doesn't recognize if there's already a mark in a certain spot and allows overwriting of already placed marks) and I was wondering if any more experienced programmers could give me some general feedback about how I could do things better. Thank you so much and I hope you're all staying safe.

```
board = ['-'] * 9

def print_board():
    print (board[0] + '|' + board[1] + '|' + board[2])
    print (board[3] + '|' + board[4] + '|' + board[5])
    print (board[6] + '|' + board[7] + '|' + board[8])




legalMoves = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print_board()

turnCount = 0
def move():



    move = int(input('Pick a number 1-9:'))
    while move not in legalMoves:
        print('Illegal move')
        move = int(input('Pick a number 1-9:'))



    marks = ['X','O']


    if turnCount % 2 == 0:
        board[move - 1] = marks[1]
    else:
        board[move - 1] = marks[0]



while True:
    if board[0] == board[1] == board[2] == 'X'\
    or board[3] == board[4] == board[5] == 'X'\
    or board[6] == board[7] == board[8] == 'X'\
    or board[0] == board[3] == board[6] == 'X'\
    or board[1] == board[4] == board[7] == 'X'\
    or board[2] == board[5] == board[8] == 'X'\
    or board[0] == board[4] == board[8] == 'X'\
    or board[2] == board[4] == board[6] == 'X' \
    or board[0] == board[1] == board[2] == 'O' \
    or board[3] == board[4] == board[5] == 'O' \
    or board[6] == board[7] == board[8] == 'O' \
    or board[0] == board[3] == board[6] == 'O' \
    or board[1] == board[4] == board[7] == 'O' \
    or board[2] == board[5] == board[8] == 'O' \
    or board[0] == board[4] == board[8] == 'O':
        print('Victory')
        break

    else:
        move()
        print_board()
        turnCount = turnCount + 1
```

Comment: This type of questions is better to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know, thank you!

Comment: You should check for a tie too, and you have lot of code repetition

Comment: See [A Guide To Code Review For Stack Overflow Users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). Basically, the difference is that SO questions need to be about a *specific problem*, and we want only the shortest code that demonstrates that problem; whereas on Code Review, code needs to be working before you ask there, and needs to be open for any kind of feedback. The latter is definitely what you want; code that's just requesting a discussion falls into https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Thanks Charles, I will post in code review

Comment: Note that I've recently reviewed a Tic Tac Toe game there, so it could be very helpful to first look at existing reviews, change your code according to the comments found, and then submit your best code at the code review site. One remark I often make there is that if you're doing the counting & math, then probably something is amiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you need to check if the user has typed
an int or something else, so that breaks your
program, also prevent the user from overwriting
existed cell input, also prevent the user from
typing a number out of range which you have
already taken care of that, so I have written
this small function to give you the correct
input and deals with wrong ones, you can use it

```
def isInt(strInt):
  for c in strInt:
    if c not in "0123456789": return False
  return True

def getNextMove():
  while True:
    moveStr = input("Pick a number 1-9: ") 
    if not isInt(moveStr): 
      print("Pls write only a number")
      continue
    move = int(moveStr)
    if move < 1 or move > 9: 
      print("Pls only 1-9 numbers are allowed")
      continue
    if board[move - 1] != "-":
      print("Pls choose an empty cell")
      continue
    return move
```

Well, if that helped, I couldn't stop my self from writing the full code for the game, I couldn't sleep anyway, so here it is, you may get some ideas, happy coding!

```
board = [" "] * 9
winner = ""

def printBoard():
  print("-" * 7)
  for i in range(3):
    print(f"|{board[i * 3]}|{board[i * 3 + 1]}|{board[i * 3 + 2]}|")
    print("-" * 7)

def isInt(strInt):
  for c in strInt:
    if c not in "0123456789": return False
  return True

def getNextMove():
  while True:
    moveStr = input("Pick a number 1-9: ") 
    if not isInt(moveStr): 
      print("Pls write only a number")
      continue
    move = int(moveStr)
    if move < 1 or move > 9: 
      print("Pls only 1-9 numbers are allowed")
      continue
    if board[move - 1] != " ":
      print("Pls choose an empty cell")
      continue
    return move

def checkHVD():
  for i in range(3):
    if board[i * 3] == board[i * 3 + 1] == board[i * 3 + 2] and board[i * 3] != " ":
      return board[i * 3]
    elif board[i] == board[i + 3] == board[i + 6] and board[i] != " ":
      return board[i]
  if (board[0] == board[4] == board[8] or board[2] == board[4] == board[6]) and board[4] != " ":
    return board[4]
  return False

for i in range(9):
  board[getNextMove() - 1] = i % 2 == 0 and "X" or "O"
  printBoard()
  winner = checkHVD();
  if winner:
    identity = winner == "X" and "first" or "second"
    print(f"The {identity} player({winner}) won")
    break

if not winner:
  print("It's a tie")
```