# How to write a Tic Tac Toe player input function in Python?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

In the program I need to write a function that takes the player's input for where they want to place the 'X' or 'O' for the Tic Tac Toe game, which would be a number between 0-8 and the function would also recognise invalid responses. An invalid response would be a number not between 0-8, anything that is not a number or a number that has been inputted previously.

**What is the problem?**

No matter what the input is the function recognises it as invalid, even if it should be valid.

Here is the code

```
def playerinput():
    
    print("Select the number on the board:")
    
    while True:
    
        playerchoice = input()
        if playerchoice.isdigit == True:
            if int(playerchoice) in validdata:
                validdata.pop(int(playerchoice))
                return int(playerchoice)
            else:
                print("That is not a valid input please enter a different value:")
            
            
        else:
            print("That is not a valid input please enter a different value:")
```

**validdata is a global variable**

```
validdata = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: Take a look on [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61603764/total-beginner-wrote-a-tic-tac-toe-game-in-python-and-would-like-some-feedback/61604049#61604049) and a [**code review for the same post**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/241730/total-beginner-tic-tac-toe-game-in-python/241732#241732)

Comment: Have you double checked `validdata` can be accessed from your program? (e.g. try to print it maybe...)

Comment: `playerchoice.isdigit` is a function. You need to call it: `playerchoice.isdigit()`.

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure the linked duplicates will help very much. It seems like OP understands the theory (although this implementation is a bit heavy-handed); the problem  is simply the typo that you pointed out.

Comment: @FabioVeronese 

I just checked that 'validdata' can be accessed from the program. When testing I discovered that 'playerchoice.isdigit' is always False for some reason.  Then I realised that I forgot to put the brackets that is why there was the error.

Comment: @deceze
Yes you are correct that was the issue it works now.